# Aggregation with two different conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'v one issue to write aggregation query. I'v 3 doc.I want filter 2 doc with some condition.In which 2 doc having same data with 1 changed value.

I have 3 entries of data in database. English is default lang for my data. In which 2 entries(one with default lang and other with 'Hindi' lang) having same data with some unique id with one diff language parameter and 3rd entry having only data in default lang another uniqueid.

Now I want data in following condition: 
1) I have have sent English as a lang parameter Then query will find out the data with english lang

2) If I send Hindi lang as a parameter then from all entries I get 2 entries one entries with hindi lang and one entry with english(default lang) as a result

Query :

**certification.find({$and: [{certificate_id: certificate_id}, {$or : [{lang : lang }, {lang : 'English'}]}]});**

**lang, certificate_id : parameter passed by user**

Please help me to write query with mongodb.

Comment: Please add your query and dummy documents that is to be queried.

Comment: please add these in your question. Not in the comments. Be precise. Refer other questions to learn how to form your questions.